# EPPlus - Update Custom Ribbon Elements

Tags: c#, xml, excel, epplus

I have a excel file which contains several items in a custom ribbon. I've added these custom elements with Microsoft's "[Custom UI Editor for Microsoft Office](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/a37ba204-28a9-4230-9d19-85ef9c29c562/custom-ui-editor-for-microsoft-office-2013-or-microsoft-office-2016?forum=worddev)", my customization looks something like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
   <ribbon>
      <tabs>
         <tab id="XXX" label="XXX" insertAfterMso="TabInsert">
            <group id="YYY" label="YYY">
                <button id="btnXXX" 
                    label="XXXX" 
                    imageMso="PivotTableNewStyle" 
                    size="large" 
                    onAction="ZZZZ" 
                    screentip="XXX" 
                    supertip="XXX" />
            </group>
        </tab>
      </tabs>
   </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

I would like to modify(Add remove elements, change elements) this header with EPPlus, is this possible? If so how would it be done?

Comment: I wouldn't expect to find what you're looking for because it's not part of the OpenXML specification. It's specific to Excel.

Comment: You can use `package.Workbook.WorkbookXml` to modify the XML directly.

Answer (score 1):

I have not found a way to do this in EPPlus, but I have found a way to edit it with the "[DocumentFormat.OpenXml](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/)" library. Specifically to access that portion of the file I use the following code:

```
((SpreadsheetDocument)document.WorkbookPart.OpenXmlPackage).RibbonAndBackstageCustomizationsPart
```

I'm still not sure if it can be done in EPPlus. Maybe in a future version...